# Rewrite url and stop rewriting

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

My apache web server rewrites all http traffic to https, but there is one url (example.com/facebook/any_word) I do not want to rewrite.
I figured if I put this rule above the rule that rewrites all http to https and put a flag L to it - it will work. But it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^/facebook/(.*)?$ /index.php/$0 [PT,L] #this rule is not applied...
#...other rules which rewrites http to https....
```

Comment: The `[L]` ends the current rewriting cycle – but when Rewriting is configured via `.htaccess`, the final rewritten URL is then again taken and put through all the rules again. I’d try with a `RewriteCond` above the Rule that does the http->https rewriting, and formulate an exception for those particular URLs there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !/facebook     [NC]
#...other rules which rewrites http to https...

RewriteRule ^/facebook/(.*)?$ /index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

I am assuming the last rule works as expected.

#### UPDATE

In case the last rule is not tested, I would suggest something like this instead:

Replace this rule above:

```
RewriteRule ^/facebook/(.*)?$ /index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

With these 2 lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php                [NC]
RewriteRule ^facebook/(.*)/?$ /index.php/facebook/$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable mod_rewrite debugging to ensure what you think should happen is actually happening. Put something similar to the following into your virtual host configuration:

```
RewriteLogLevel 8
RewriteLog /var/log/rewrite.log
```

Note that this syntax changed in Apache 2.4 so you may need to change it if not running < Apache 2.4.